# More efficient ES6 imports

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I read somewhere (forgot the source, unfortunately), that it's more efficient somehow to do this:

```
import _find from 'lodash/find';
```

as opposed to:

```
import _ from 'lodash'; // just to use _.find
```

I understand how it could be more efficient to import a single function, but where is the efficiency/performance gain exactly? Is it webpack-related? If I'm not using webpack as my build engine, does it matter?

Comment: Yes, it's about smaller module sizes. Both for clientside builds, as well as build times in general.

Comment: In other words, when building for production, it will only include the lodash code for `find` if I import via the first method, right? Is this a webpack thing, or does it apply to ES6 in general?

Comment: It applies to modules in general, regardless which module system or module bundler you use. There are however bundlers that remove dead (unneeded) code automatically even if you import the big module; this trades build size for build time.

Comment: @Bergi Follow-up: is `import _find from 'lodash/find'` the same as `import { find as _find } from 'lodash'`? Or does the latter still pull in the entire lodash codebase?

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to pull in entire `lodash` (but only make `find` available), however intelligent bundlers such as rollup aim to avoid that if the module is built properly.

Comment: Got it. So `import _find from 'lodash/find'` is the safest way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you import a big library, you import the whole thing (at least with most bundlers), since there is no clear way to distinguish what is necessary from the object you imported.

I'm not too familiar with lodash but it's entry point should look something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  find: require('./find.js')
  filter: require('./filter.js')
  // rest of the exposed functions
}
```

With the second import style you got this whole object, but you only need 1 function from all of this.

So if you do this:

```
import _ from 'lodash'
```

You will end up with the whole lodash library packed into your bundle, while if you do this:

```
import find from 'lodash/find'
```

You will only have `find` and it's dependencies, resulting in a considerably smaller bundle size.

Comment: What about: import {find} from 'lodash'

Comment: @KenFehling If you are importing from an es6 bundle it's ok. If you are importing that from a library eg.: lodash, it's basically still has to load the whole thing first, so you are better of with the last option in the answer.